# graph sharepoint filter One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I'm encountering an issue when using filter one particular list.

Request :

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{id}:/commercial:/lists/{id}/items?filter=id eq 7941
```

response :

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "-2130575340, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException",
    "message":
      "One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these fields.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "3573cb36-5c0f-47ff-8723-b829d1dc4b8a",
      "date": "2018-03-28T13:49:59"
    }
  }
}
```

Of course, I tried to filter with other fields and it still doesn't work.
I really don't know, how I can resolve it.
Could you help me?